# How to add the data After reallocating a memory using a realloc() function?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Consider I have a string called `"bhuvanesh"` , to store that string , Initially allocate the memory using `malloc()`

```
   char *ptr=(char *)malloc(sizeof("bhuvanesh"));
   sprintf(ptr,"bhuvanesh");
```

Then I want to add the string with the previously stored memory , the string is `"waran"`. so I am using `realloc()`

```
 ptr=(char *)realloc(ptr,15);
```

The function `realloc()` will return the starting address, so concatenate the string I can use `strcat()` function

```
  strcat(ptr,"waran");
```

or else I can do like that

```
    char *p=ptr;
    p=p+sizeof("bhuvanesh");

    sprintf(p,"waran\n");
```

Is there is any way to do this ?

Comment: You just gave two ways.

Comment: @RaymondChen - yes I want to know , any easiest way is available to do that?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh What do you imagine you'll find that is simpler than the strcat example you already gave? It's one function call that takes the two parameters that any other solution is also going to require.

Comment: Better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

This is correct:

> ```
>   strcat(ptr,"waran");
> ```

This is faulty:

> ```
>     char *p=ptr;
>     p=p+sizeof("bhuvanesh");
>
>     sprintf(p,"waran\n");
> ```

`p=p+sizeof("bhuvanesh")` results in `p` pointing *after* the string-terminating `'\0'`; correct would be

```
    p += sizeof"bhuvanesh" - 1;
```

or

```
    p += strlen(p);
```

Plus `sprintf(p,"waran\n")` adds 6 bytes to the string, but you have only reallocated 5 more, so either

```
 ptr = realloc(ptr, 16);
```

or dropping the `'\n'`, e. g.

```
    strcpy(p, "waran");
```

would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the headache to the OS; not with you; I mean don't use strlen, strcpy and using + to find the exact locations; Now with this below approach you are done with what you want; Keep it simply stylish (KISS)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main() 
{
    char *ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof("bhuvanesh"));
    sprintf(ptr, "bhuvanesh");

    ptr = (char *)realloc(ptr, 15);

    sprintf(ptr, "%swaran", ptr);
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```